# What are the factors that determine resistivity? What is the resistivity of vacuum?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-resistance

What determines if a material will have a high resistivity or not? Why is that insulators and semiconductors have negative temperature coefficient?

Since electrons can flow in a vacuum tube and in a vacuum, does it mean that vacuum can be a perfect conductor? What is its resistivity?

Comment: related to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/150680/

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell how detailed of an answer you're looking for.

This is the simplest model, for solids: In a conductor, a large number of valence electrons are very loosely bound to a 'home' nucleus and so are essentially free to be pushed through the conductor by an external electric field supplied by a battery (for example). When pushed away from their homes, they become conduction electrons that are not tied to any particular nucleus.

In an insulator, nearly all of the valence electrons are very strongly bound to their home nucleus. An external electric field of an ordinary magnitude, i.e. what an ordinary battery would provide, will not pull them away. Semiconductors lie between these extremes but don't easily fit into this very simplified explanation.

The next step in a path toward a more complete description of what is happening involves quantum mechanical topics such as band gaps. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity) is a good summary.

As for the temperature coefficient, a negative value indicates that at higher temperatures valence electrons become more loosely bound, and therefore are more easily pulled away from their home nuclei to become conduction electrons.

The resistivity of the vacuum is zero. There is nothing there (literally) to provide any kind mechanical resistance to the flow of charged particles.